# Facebook Comments Linkback URL

Tags: facebook

I am wanting to add the Facebook Comments plugin to a webpage. When the user makes a comment, I know that it will show up on their Facebook wall, posting an active link back to the webpage.

Is is possible to make that link go back to any url I want?  Or do I have to use the url of the current page where my Facebook Comments module is located?

Answer (score 0):

The comments plugin will always link users to the URL the comments were added to - what you do after that is up to you, you could redirect with your server or client-side code if you wanted to.